# Agrupar elementos y mostrar imagen en html según resultados de json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo 2 inquietudes espero me puedan apoyar:

Tengo los siguentes datos en mi Json:

```
{
    "name": "Budew",
    "eggType": "2 km",
    "isAdventureSync": false,
    "image": "/pokemon_icon_406_00.png",
    "canBeShiny": true,
    "combatPower": {
        "min": 448,
        "max": 489
    },
    "isRegional": false
},
```

Este es mi código con el que recojo datos y muestro en html:

```js
document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML = 'Un momento, por favor...';
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigfoott/ScrapedDuck/data/eggs.json';
request.open("GET", url);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        let html = '<ul class="egg-list-flex">';
        posts.forEach(function (post, index) {
            console.log(`${index} : ${post.name}`);
            html += `<li class="egg-list-item">
                    <div class="egg-list-img egg2km">
                    <img src="${post.image}"></div>
                    <img class="shiny-icon" src="./${post.canBeShiny}.png" alt="shiny">
                    <span class="hatch-pkmn">${post.name}</span>
                    <br>
                    <div class="font-size-smaller color-555555">
                    <span class="font-size-x-small">CP ${post.combatPower.min} - ${post.combatPower.max}</span>
                    </div>
                </li>`;
        });
        html += '</ul>';
        document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="response"></div>
```

Me gustaría mostrar una imagen `src="./${post.canBeShiny}.png"` según el resultado que obtenga: (`true` o `false`) en el json "canBeShiny": true.

Lo otro es agruparlos, segun: "eggType": "2 km", de 5 y 10; y mostrar en mi html agrupados.

Este es mi resultado actual de html:

[image: Este es mi resultado en html:]

lo que necesito es agruparlos:

[image: algo asi]

agruparlos según resultados de mi jquery ( "eggType": "2 km" ) y mostrar las estrellas en la parte superior derecha según ("canBeShiny": true,)

Comment: y que has intentado? recuerda que toda pregunta debe tener una demostracion de esfuerzo, osea un [example]

Comment: ademas la explicacion de lo que buscas es bastante mala, intenta detallar tu problema y lo que buscas mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero no uso un `<ul>` para todos los pokemones sino que uso un `<ul>` para cada categoría y antes de ellos agrego las cabeceras "2km eggs", "5kmeggs" y "10kmeggs" con un `<h1>` y una línea con `<hr>`. Después uso el operador ternario para si isShiny == true coloque la imagen shiny.jgp, de lo contrario agrego una imagen de 1x1 pixeles  transparente. Uso `insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",)` para agregar los pokemones en la lista de su categoría, justo antes de su ultimo nodo hijo.

```js
document.querySelector('.response').innerHTML += 'Un momento, por favor...';
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bigfoott/ScrapedDuck/data/eggs.json';
request.open("GET", url);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    const posts = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    posts.forEach((post) => {
      if (post.eggType == "2 km") {
        // despues del ultimo hijo del <ul "2kmegg"></ul> agrego el siguiente fragmento de documento
        document.getElementById("2kmeggs").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
        <li class="egg-list-item">
          <div class="egg-list-img egg2km">
          <img src="${post.image}"></div>
          <img class="shiny-icon" src=${post.canBeShiny ? "./pokeimg/shiny.jpg" : ""} alt="shiny"> <!-- Uso del operador ternario! -->
          <span class="hatch-pkmn">${post.name}</span>
          <br>
          <div class="font-size-smaller color-555555">
          <span class="font-size-x-small">CP ${post.combatPower.min} - ${post.combatPower.max}</span>
          </div>
        </li>`
        );
      }
      if (post.eggType == "5 km") {
        document.getElementById("5kmeggs").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
        <li class="egg-list-item">
          <div class="egg-list-img egg2km">
          <img src="${post.image}"></div>
          <img class="shiny-icon" src=${post.canBeShiny ? "./pokeimg/shiny.jpg" : ""} alt="shiny">
          <span class="hatch-pkmn">${post.name}</span>
          <br>
          <div class="font-size-smaller color-555555">
          <span class="font-size-x-small">CP ${post.combatPower.min} - ${post.combatPower.max}</span>
          </div>
        </li>`
        );
      } 
      if (post.eggType == "10 km") {  
        document.getElementById("10kmeggs").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ` /
        <li class="egg-list-item">
          <div class="egg-list-img egg2km">
          <img src="${post.image}"></div>
          <img class="shiny-icon" src=${post.canBeShiny ? "./pokeimg/shiny.jpg" : "./pokeimg/noShiny.png"} alt="shiny">
          <span class="hatch-pkmn">${post.name}</span>
          <br>
          <div class="font-size-smaller color-555555">
          <span class="font-size-x-small">CP ${post.combatPower.min} - ${post.combatPower.max}</span>
          </div>
        </li>`
        );
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="response">
    <h1>2km eggs</h1>
    <ul id="2kmeggs"></ul>
    <hr>
    <h1>5km eggs</h1>
    <ul id="5kmeggs"></ul>
    <hr>
    <h1>10km eggs</h1>
    <ul id="10kmeggs"></ul>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts2.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

La imagen del shiny funciona solo que como te imaginaras, la imagen esta en mi equipo y no se como importarlo aca. Pero si lo copias y pegas en tu IDE funciona siempre y cuando pongas la ruta que desees.

Comment: Gracias, voy a estudiar bien tu codigo. Muy agradecido